# Vuetify autocomplete not showing dropdown when using mutiple prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I am using v-autocomplete component of vuetify and the issue I am facing here is, when I add the prop multiple to autocomplete then the dropdown doesn't show and when I remove multiple then the dropdown shows. Below is how I am implementing it. Please help me find where I am going wrong. I am using vuetify version 2.3.10 .

```
<v-autocomplete
 ref="office_locations"
 :items="locations"
 v-model="office.location_ids"
 label='Office Locations'
 item-text='name'
 item-value='id'
 multiple
 attach
 required>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Locations data is as follows.

```
locations: [{id: 1, name: "Toronto", label: "Toronto"},
{id: 2, name: "New York", label: "New York"},
{id: 3, name: "San Jose", label: "San Jose"},
{id: 4, name: "Vancouver", label: "Vancouver"}]
```

Update 1

I tried inspecting the v-autocomplete component and v-menu is empty
[image]

Comment: it should work I'm trying out your code and it works fine

Comment: Tried it too and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-vuetify-gunue Exact same version of `vuetify`, there is some missing CSS but the logic is working properly.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim please check update 1

Comment: @kissu please check update 1

Comment: What should we see here ? Inspect it with Vue devtools rather than regular HTML/CSS ones. Also, state is properly populated no ?

Comment: @kissu what should I check for in vue dev tools?

What do you mean by state is properly populated

Comment: On my linked example, you can see that `office.location_ids` contains all the values that you have selected. You can double check your local state `office.location_ids` in the vue tools, you'll see an array likewise.

Comment: @kissu yes I can see the values of office.location_ids. So basically I was using v-select before and now I am switching to v-autocomplete. So with multiple prop used in v-select I am able to select multiple options as the dropdown opens but when I switch to v-autocomplete I can still see the preselected values but the dropdown doesn't open now to change the select values.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction link ? Works fine on the codesandbox so far.

Comment: Actually I tried reproduction it on codepen but it works there. I copied the code for autocomplete with multiple prop from https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#api and even that doesn't work on my local.

Comment: was this ever resolved? we're having the same issue and I cannot replicate this in a codepen